# R Studio Too Slow to Run

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I recently had a computer crash and had to reinstall R 3.6.1 and R Studio on my new laptop. Everything runs fine in RGUI but almost nothing runs in R Studio. For example, when opening the Global Options, it says Reading Options... and nothing has happened for the last five minutes. Simple commands such as 2+2 do not run. I have attached an image showing the options issue.

One thing I noticed under Choose R Installation is that there are two versions of R, which I have attached a screenshot of. Is this an issue?[image]

In addition, any time I click on ANYTHING, it takes minutes to load. An example is below:

[image]

UPDATE WITH LOG FILES:

05 Oct 2019 00:11:51 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
05 Oct 2019 00:13:04 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
05 Oct 2019 00:56:15 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in base::try(tmp, TRUE) : object 'tmp' not found|||]; OCCURRED AT: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::EvalType) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\r\RExec.cpp:171; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::modules::packages::enquePackageStateChanged(void) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionPackages.cpp:555
05 Oct 2019 00:56:15 [rsession-Jason.Motley] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool __cdecl rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(class rstudio_boost::shared_ptr,const class rstudio_boost::function) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:140
05 Oct 2019 01:43:04 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
05 Oct 2019 01:54:45 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 14:19:08 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 14:33:57 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in base::try(wordcloud_function, TRUE) : |||  object 'wordcloud_function' not found|||]; OCCURRED AT: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::EvalType) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\r\RExec.cpp:171; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::session::modules::packages::`anonymous-namespace'::getPackageState(const struct rstudio::core::json::JsonRpcRequest &,class rstudio::core::json::JsonRpcResponse *) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionPackages.cpp:542
06 Oct 2019 14:35:42 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 14:40:18 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 14:52:12 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 15:10:29 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
06 Oct 2019 16:16:51 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
07 Oct 2019 19:55:22 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
07 Oct 2019 20:15:15 [rsession-Jason.Motley] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=subscript out of bounds]; OCCURRED AT: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::EvalType) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\r\RExec.cpp:171; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::modules::packages::enquePackageStateChanged(void) C:\jenkins\workspace\IDE\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionPackages.cpp:555

Answer (score 1):

The logfile could help us go ahead, because there is an entry in there which could explain your stucking RStudio environment:

```
ERROR system error 10053
```

The related line says the external connection your RStudio is trying to establish was aborted - that explains the stucking envrionment after start:

```
(An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]
```

10053 often occurs with routers, firewalls and proxies. Are you using any of these?
Additionally I recommend to take a look into get_events: This R-function can be used for scraping bey defining cyclic running events. An idea would be to inactivate them temporally, restart your RStudio environment and check the behaviour and the logfile whether you keep having those unexpected effects.

- Additional infos
  1.)
  get_events: Scrape the number of advertised events in Bath for each day
  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BANEScarparkinglite/versions/0.1.2/topics/get_events
  2.)
  Socket Error 10053 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
  https://wiki.pscs.co.uk/how_to:10053

Answer (score 0):

Could you please execute this commend in the Console part of R (not RStudio)?

```
sessionInfo()
```

This would do nothing else than collecting additional informations and print them inside the console window - so far: no worry.
Please post them in here.

As next please open RStudio, reproduce the stucking effect and close it again. Afterwards reopen it and post in here please the log.
You can find the RStudio logs under: [There the logs can be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7uBw.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Here is the session info: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

Comment: Log files are added to original comment.

Comment: The logfile could help us go ahead, because there is